# How can I create a schema for a no-delimiter file in PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a CDR which is of following type:

```
068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1MOCCUST10612287077212:07:1201/01/2012
068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1MTCCUST20600000001312:15:0901/01/2012
068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1SMSCUST10613637193012:18:1801/01/2012
068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1SMSCUST10612899062012:21:0701/01/2012
```

I have to load this file using PIG with the following schema:

```
MSIDN:IMSI:IMEI:PLAN:CALL_TYPE:CORRESP_TYPE:CORRESP_ISDN:DURATION:TIME:DATE
```

I know the length of each schema, but I cannot find out how to load the data in proper format. Here is the required length format, starting from the first column:

```
13
15
12
5
3
5
11
1
hh:mm:ss
dd/mm/yyyy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution can be load using normal pig loader and then pass it through an UDF to get the columns. I will try to come with the code and post it tonight. As promised:

```
    ]$ more cdr.txt
    068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1MOCCUST10612287077212:07:1201/01/2012
    068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1MTCCUST20600000001312:15:0901/01/2012
    068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1SMSCUST10613637193012:18:1801/01/2012
    068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1SMSCUST10612899062012:21:0701/01/2012

    ]$ more cdr.py
    import sys

    def mysubstr(input,start,nc):

            return input[start:nc]

    ]$ more cdr.pig
    REGISTER 'cdr.py' using jython as mysubstr;
    A = LOAD 'cdr.txt' AS (inp:chararray);
    B = FOREACH A GENERATE                
    inp, mysubstr.mysubstr(inp,0,13), 
    mysubstr.mysubstr(inp,14,29), 
    mysubstr.mysubstr(inp,30,42);
    DUMP B;
```

Output:
(068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1MOCCUST10612287077212:07:1201/01/2012,0683737481022,810016768247735,905149071PLA)
(068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1MTCCUST20600000001312:15:0901/01/2012,0683737481022,810016768247735,905149071PLA)
(068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1SMSCUST10613637193012:18:1801/01/2012 ,0683737481022,810016768247735,905149071PLA)
(068373748102208100167682477351905149071PLAN1SMSCUST10612899062012:21:0701/01/2012,0683737481022,810016768247735,905149071PLA)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at FixedWidthLoader from piggybank for loading position delimited files (I had used it for loading a file similar to one you mentioned here).

For example, We can specify the column position and column mapping as follows

A = LOAD 'inputfile.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.FixedWidthLoader(
'1-6,7-5', 'WRITE_HEADER','col1: chararray, col2: chararray' );

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/FixedWidthLoader.html

Comment: Can you please explain this query in the above scenario, so that i can understand better

Answer (score 0):

PigStorage (the default load and store function) does not handle this
case. You would need to write you own load function. Using
PigStorage as a model this should not be too difficult. Instead of
looking for field separators you just parse out the fields based on
length, and then use standard string functions to trim the white space.

read this http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html#Store+Functions